# Why send method of Electron does not working from the main process?

Tags: javascript, process, electron, ipcrenderer, ipcmain

I'm in big trouble. I checked other solutions but nothing helped me.
I don't understand why the "[send](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args)" method doesn't work here. No exceptions, no messages or anything else.

I tried wrapping the send method in another method but it failed.
I tried using the "[sendToFrame](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendtoframeframeid-channel-args)" method but it failed too.

main:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
let win;
function createWindow () {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
       width: 800,
       height: 600,
       frame: true,
       autoHideMenuBar: true,
       webPreferences: {
           nodeIntegration: true,
           allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
           contextIsolation: false, // false if you want to run 2e2 test with Spectron
           enableRemoteModule: true,
       }
    });

    win.loadFile('src/home.html');
    win.webContents.openDevTools();

    ipcMain.on('main', (event, msg) => {
        sendData()    // Does not work.
        event.reply('new-client', 'res')    // It works.
    })

    function sendData() {
        win.webContents.send('new-client', {wsh: 'wshsdqsdqs'});
    }
};

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);
```

Below, the "ipcRenderer.send" method works. It sends data to the main process but receives no response when I use the "webContents.send" method (in the main process).

new-client.js:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
const {resolve} = require('path');
const {Message} = require(resolve('src/js/shared/class/message/message.js'));


ipcRenderer.on('new-client', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(event)
    console.log(arg)
})

async function send() {
    const msg = new Message(
        'new-client',
        'clients',
        true
    );
    ipcRenderer.send('main', msg);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot this...
I sent the data to the wrong window.

You can use [BrowserWindow.getAllWindows](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetallwindows), then send the data to a specific window.

Personally, I added an event when windows are open, in this way I can properly send data and manage windows.

Comment: not sure why it wouldnt let me call it directly with/from the `BrowserWindow` object

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: honestly im now not sure what i meant lol